nReco pdf font issue
I am using nReco pdf generator within  an Azure Function App. The fonts on the generated pdf does not reflect the fonts specified in the supplied html. In fact any font specified in the html, the output remains same.
Is there a list of fonts that I could use with nReco pdf on Azure Function App?

This is a known issue with Azure Apps hosting environment (btw it is mentioned in FAQ section "Technical limitations" here): custom fonts (that are specified with CSS @font-face) cannot be loaded because of GDI API restrictions that are present when .NET app is hosted in Azure Apps (wkhtmltopdf simply cannot 'load' custom fonts, and fallbacks to 'default' font, this is usually Arial). You can use only 'standard' Windows-system installed fonts like Arial, Times New Roman etc.
Note that this restriction is only Azure Apps, usual Azure VMs doesn't have it. One more alternative is using containerized Azure Function app (where you can prepare own Linux-based image with included wkhtmltopdf) for your PDF generation service.
